# Как реализовать авторизацию по токену в .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть фрон на angular 2, есть бэк на .net core. Необходимо реализовать авторизацию по токену, через сторонние сайты типо вк. после чего все общение бэка с фронтом должно осуществлятся через токен. подскажите как реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Во первых надо установить пакеты **IdentityServer4**.
Сами пакеты:

```
IdentityServer4
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation
IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework
```

Далее необходимо сделать по образцу: https://gist.github.com/gromanev/4da63142825798927375a3da342e65b8

Опять таки важно сопоставлять с официальной документацией и предложенным кодом, ведь я использую внутри свои сервисы которые не привожу в листинге. И Вам предстоит работа с определением где мой код, а где код IdentityServer`a.

Удачи!